# Jquery mobile header android next field

Tags: android, forms, jquery-mobile

So, i'm scratching my head here in frustration at the android browser! Android version 2.3.6.
What is wrong with this thing? The next and before(perhaps previous) buttons
do not work! ...on some basic jquery form fields.

Having:

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
 <img src="img/logo.png" style="margin-top:15px;">
</div>

<div data-role="content">  
  <form action="#" method="get">
     <div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
    </div>

 <div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="textarea">Textarea:</label>
    <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
  </div>
   </form>

</div>
</div>
```

But... if I remove  data-role="header" the damn thing start working??!!

No problem of course on the Safari browser! Which is superb as usual.

Please can somebody help me?

Comment: What button's ? I don't know what do you want? I test on android emulator and all work's fine. Please would you depict more ask you.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know how to describe it, its just unstable and works sometimes... Need to test this more until I can explain whats really goin wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that if you want to add a back button you need to add a `data-add-back-btn="true"` to your page `div`.  I don't see that in your example.  OTOH, the hardware `back` button should work as well.

What is it that doesn't work?

Comment: Ok I tried adding four input fields in a page, and let jquery mobile style these like it does default. On Android 2.3.6, i can use the UI android next button one step down and one step up again. Cannot jump from field 2 to 3...

Android 2.3.6 built in browser!

Of course if I do not use jquery mobile, and leave the input fields unthemed, it works.

Answer (score 0):

So, after many hours... i noticed stuff in my css was breaking this functionality...

```
    /*article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, 
    section { display: block; } audio, canvas, video { display: inline-block; 
    *display: inline; *zoom: 1; } audio:not([controls]) { display: none; }
    [hidden] { display: none; } html { font-size: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }*/
```

Removed above and it worked.

Not sure, might be the boilerplate used.